# Why does my C program crash after the first for loop is completed?

Tags: c

So basically after the computer finishes asking you to input all of the data (the first for loop) the compiler just crashes and I'm confused. I'm using code blocks 16.01 with the mingw32 gcc compiler.

As A side note, if you have the time, could you give me some ideas as to how you would improve this program? I'm talking efficiency wise and less redundancy. It's supposed to allow the user to input 4 different data points for 5 different stocks, and then calculate initial cost, current cost, and profit for each of the data points for each stock, then display them out to the user. As you can see, I just shoved all the data points for all the stocks in a single array (called "cost") and just did my calculations within the array. I know the logic and execution is messy, so that's why I'm asking you guys for alternatives.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main () {
    const char *stock [5];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    float stockData[4], cost[15];
    stock[0] = "IBM";
    stock[1] = "ORACLE";
    stock[2] = "SUN MICRO";
    stock[3] = "LINKSYS";
    stock[4] = "CISCO";

    for (;i<=4;i++){
        printf("Enter the number of shares, buying price per share, current price per share, and the yearly fees for %s: \n", stock[i]);
        scanf ("%f%f%f%f",&stockData[0],&stockData[1],&stockData[2],&stockData[3]);
            if (i==0){
                cost[0] = (stockData[0]*stockData[1]);
                cost[1] = (stockData[0]*stockData[2]);
                cost[2] = (cost[1]-cost[0]-stockData[3]);
                memset(stockData, 0, sizeof(stockData));
                }
            if (i==1){
                cost[3] = (stockData[0]*stockData[1]);
                cost[4] = (stockData[0]*stockData[2]);
                cost[5] = (cost[4]-cost[3]-stockData[3]);
                memset(stockData, 0, sizeof(stockData));
            }
            if (i==2){
                cost[6] = (stockData[0]*stockData[1]);
                cost[7] = (stockData[0]*stockData[2]);
                cost[8] = (cost[7]-cost[6]-stockData[3]);
                memset(stockData, 0, sizeof(stockData));
            }
            if (i==3){
                cost[9] = (stockData[0]*stockData[1]);
                cost[10] = (stockData[0]*stockData[2]);
                cost[11] = (cost[10]-cost[9]-stockData[3]);
                memset(stockData, 0, sizeof(stockData));
            }
            if (i==4){
                cost[12] = (stockData[0]*stockData[1]);
                cost[13] = (stockData[0]*stockData[2]);
                cost[14] = (cost[13]-cost[12]-stockData[3]);
                memset(stockData, 0, sizeof(stockData));
            }
        }

        for (;j<=4;j++){
            printf("Stock Name: %s, Initial Cost: $%.2f, Current Cost: $.2%f, Profit: $.2%f ", stock[j],cost[++k],cost[++k],cost[++k]);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: it was the array lengths that was causing the problem. I fixed it in the original code, now I'm just getting weird outputs. I will update again If I can't fix it myself.

Comment: Run your program under a debugger or `valgrind`, then [edit] your question and add *where* it crashes.

Comment: `const char *stock [4];` --> `const char *stock [5];`,  `float stockData[3], cost[14];` --> `float stockData[4], cost[15];`

Comment: oh yaaaaa...... thanks! Now that it runs, I am getting some weird outputs. I'm going to try to look at it myself and see where I went wrong before I ask you guys for help on this one.

Comment: Also `printf("Stock Name:...,cost[++k],cost[++k],cost[++k]);` is UB(Undefined Behavior).

Comment: so then I can't increment the K variable after I call? would I just have make another loop for that?

Comment: change to like `cost[k],cost[k+1],cost[k+2].. k += 3;`

Answer (score 1):

Check your stock array. You defined it for 4 elements, but assigned 5 elements.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13643591)

Comment: @Deepak As it turns out, this does answer the original question, completely. The question has been edited since then, see question edit history.